# Is pasteurized or non-pasteurized milk healthier for an adult male in his early 40s?

Tags: milk

Taste is irrelevant. Health effects is the more important consideration. Which is a healthier choice for an adult male in his early 40s? Pasteurized or non-pasteurized milk? How much should he drink if he is an office worker who does not work out a lot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pasteurized milk is perfectly safe for people of all ages but raw milk may or may not be. According to the CDC:

> Raw milk is milk from any animal that has not been pasteurized to kill
>   harmful bacteria. Raw milk can carry harmful bacteria and other germs
>   that can make you very sick or kill you. While it is possible to get
>   foodborne illnesses from many different foods, raw milk is one of the
>   riskiest of all.
>
> Some people who chose raw milk thinking they would improve their
>   health instead found themselves (or their loved ones) sick in a
>   hospital for several weeks due to infections caused by germs in raw
>   milk. Getting sick from raw milk can mean many days of diarrhea,
>   stomach cramping, and vomiting. Some people who drank raw milk have
>   developed severe or even life-threatening diseases, including
>   Guillain-Barré syndrome, which can cause paralysis, and hemolytic
>   uremic syndrome, which can result in kidney failure, stroke, and even
>   death.

Age is largely irrelevant unless you're very old or very young. On this subject the CDC has this to say:

> The risk of getting sick from drinking contaminated raw milk is
>   greater for infants and young children, older adults, pregnant women,
>   and people with weakened immune systems, such as people with cancer,
>   an organ transplant, or HIV, than it is for healthy older children and
>   adults. But healthy people of any age can get very sick or even die if
>   they drink raw milk contaminated with harmful germs.

As for how much to drink, there's no right or wrong answer for that. Drink as much as you like but keep in mind that whole milk is fairly high in calories.

https://www.cdc.gov/foodsafety/rawmilk/raw-milk-questions-and-answers.html